# MySQL Lower Query Cost in Explain Plan Resulted to Higher Time to Execute

Tags: mysql

I am running on a MySQL 8.0.28.

I have a query that I want to optimize and I am confused with the explain plan and actual result. In the original query, this is the explain plan (I truncated what I thought are irrelevant info for brevity):

```
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "119315.73"
  ...
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "119216.07",
        "eval_cost": "99.67",
        "prefix_cost": "119315.73",
        "data_read_per_join": "389K"
      },
```

And this is what the proposed query (it has a join which is why there is a nested loop in the explain plan) looks like:

```
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "47151.19"
    },
  ...
  "nested_loop": [
     "cost_info": {
      "read_cost": "1.33",
      "eval_cost": "21.00",
      "prefix_cost": "22.33",
      "data_read_per_join": "29K"
     ...
     "cost_info": {
       "read_cost": "42792.67",
       "eval_cost": "289.05",
       "prefix_cost": "47151.19",
       "data_read_per_join": "1M"
```

So, the query cost on the proposed query is 2.5 times better, right? And yet when I run the actual query, the result is this:

```
original query: 103 seconds
proposed query: 394 seconds
```

Then I ran an `explain analyze` and here are the results:
For the original query:

```
EXPLAIN | -> Aggregate: count(tablet0_.id)  (cost=118391.23 rows=997) (actual time=362.472..362.473 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Filter: ((tablet0_.draft = 0) and (tablet0_.deleted = 0))  (cost=118291.57 rows=997) (actual time=0.035..358.538 rows=69394 loops=1)
        -> Index range scan on tablet0_ using A_IDX over (baz_id = 207451 AND status = 1 AND 1 < owner_id) OR (baz_id = 207451 AND status = 2 AND 1 < owner_id), with index condition: ((tablet0_.baz_id = 207451) and (tablet0_.status in (1,2)) and (tablet0_.owner_id > 1))  (cost=118291.57 rows=99666) (actual time=0.034..349.943 rows=69411 loops=1)
```

For the proposed query:

```
EXPLAIN | -> Aggregate: count(tablet0_.id)  (cost=47440.21 rows=2891) (actual time=1573.092..1573.093 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=47151.16 rows=2891) (actual time=1107.504..1569.196 rows=69391 loops=1)
        -> Covering index lookup on _fooders u_IDX baz_TYPE_IDX (foo_baz_id=207451)  (cost=22.33 rows=210) (actual time=0.032..0.113 rows=210 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (tablet0_.owner_id > 1)  (cost=203.78 rows=14) (actual time=5.931..7.449 rows=330 loops=210)
            -> Index lookup on tablet0_ using foo_IDX (foo_id=_boos.foo_id, draft=0, deleted=0), with index condition: (tablet0_.status in (1,2))  (cost=203.78 rows=206) (actual time=0.660..7.352 rows=1509 loops=210)
```

I think this line in output of the explain analyze in the proposed query

```
Nested loop inner join  (cost=47151.16 rows=2891) (actual time=1107.504..1569.196 rows=69391 loops=1)
```

actually made the optimizer think that the rows were only 2891 but in reality, there were really 69391 rows. This is probably why it took longer for the proposed query to run?

EDIT: Here are the queries.
This is the original query.

```
select count(testtable0_.id) as x1_ 
from test_tickets testtable0_ 
where testtable0_.baz_id=505 
and testtable0_.deleted=0 
and testtable0_.draft=0 
and (testtable0_.status in (1 , 2)) 
and testtable0_.owner_id>1\G
```

This is the proposed query.

```
select count(testtable0_.id) as x1_ 
from test_tickets testtable0_ 
where testtable0_.fol_id in (select id from test_folders where baz_id=505) 
and testtable0_.deleted=0 
and testtable0_.draft=0 
and (testtable0_.status in (1 , 2)) 
and testtable0_.owner_id>1\G
```

Comment: "Cost" is an estimate.  When the data is distributed in unexpected ways, the cost can be misleading.  We may be able to explain further if we see the query.  (And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` may be helpful.)

Comment: I understand that "cost" is an estimate, I was just surprised that it was too far from the actual result. I also added the queries.